# Need to store a song from the iPod in NSUserDefaults. Nearly figured it out, need help getting there though?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

So this is what i have so far:

```
-(void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // Assign the selected item(s) to the music player and start playback.
self.selectedSong = mediaItemCollection;

    MPMediaItem *chosenItem = mediaItemCollection.representativeItem;
    NSLog(@"chosenItem: %@", chosenItem);
    persistentID = [chosenItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]; //persistentID is an NSString.
    NSLog(@"persistentID: %@", persistentID);
    [prefs setValue:persistentID forKey:@"persistentIDKey"];
    [prefs synchronize];
```

}

But now i need to figure out what to put in the part of the script where i want it retrieved. This would be the standard way of doing that..

```
[self.musicPlayer stop];
[self.musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:*ITEM HERE*];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

But i'm unsure what to put in there. Persistent ID doesn't work. I can also get any other properties from the song using my above method, not just persistentID. So if i require any others, then i can get those too. Help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate * predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:storedPID forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
MPMediaQuery * query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates: [NSSet setWithObject: predicate]];
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:query];
[self.musicPlayer play];
[query release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware, as per Apple's docs:

> The value of the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID identifier persists across application launches and across syncs that do not change the sync status of the media item.**The value is not guaranteed to persist across a sync/unsync/sync cycle.**

I have never come across an instance where this is has been an issue, however this has been the case since `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` was introduced in iOS 3.0